# TFS 2015 team web access empty code and build tabs

Tags: tfs-2015, team-explorer

We recently migrated from TFS 2008 to Tfs 2015, The code and the build and WorkItems window was showing only blank window .
how do we fix this
Team web access is allowed for all 
Licenses are set up to allow web access all features

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite Strange and very difficult to figure out.
I tried all possible options.
IE Browser gave an error that some of the features are not configured.
But I was able to access that in VS 2012 , Vs 2015 client IDE's
so I wasn't convinces by the browser Tip.

**

> Finally I used F12 in IE to find that the Options verb settings was denied in IIS 8 in Win 2012, where our TFS 2015 App Tier server was hosted

**

**In IIS 8, Go to “Request Filtering” under the IIS website and check the default setting was set to deny any verb that’s not listed explicitly to be allowed.

Issue was resolved on allowing the verb “OPTIONS” explicitly in that tab. 
see the Picture attached for reference 
Looks Like TFS web access needs that verb and we would see blank page of 404 error in new installations of TFS 2015
**[image: TFS 2015 IIS setttings for proper full TWA team web access]